# How to create an emailmessage object of a string (containing the email)

Tags: string, email, object, gmail

I have an application that is retrieving emails from GMail (the David R Goben example). I get each email back in a string (containing the complete email, but not in a handy format). How do I get this string in some kind of emailmessage object so that I can extract the Subject, From, To, Body etc. easily ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: I tried Google, and looked at the system.net.mail(.mailmessage) class ... but found nothing that looked suitable. There is no code for this problem yet. I have a string containing one whole email, and I want it in some kind of existing object so that I can extract f.e. Subject via a property.

Answer (score 0):

Probably with "not in a handy format" you mean "mime email", so
save the mime email into a text file, e.g. email.txt in the same folder with your code.py.
Then use the code below (in your code.py) to get the email object

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
with open("email.txt") as fp:
msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content(fp.read())
```

then check the type:

```
type(msg)
```

You'll get: `email.message.EmailMessage`